# Promise not getting resolved

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have problem when calling promise from PO. In PO it works OK but in main test page it gives undefined value. Like function on main page is called before promise is resolved

PO code

```
this.Email = function (){
    this.userIcon.getText(this.userIcon).then(function (text){
        this.email=text.slice(5);
        console.log(this.email);
        return this.email
    });
```

Code in main test page

```
email = data.Email();
```

---

Sorry here is the whole code from PO

```
var data = function(){
this.user = 'user';
this.pass = 'pass';
this.usrform = element(by.css("input[formControlName=username]"));
this.passinput = element(by.css("input[formControlName=password]"));
this.button = element(by.tagName('button'));
this.text = 'Something smart'
this.dir=Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
this.subID;
this.dropdown = element.all(by.css("mat-option"));
this.datepicker =  element.all(by.xpath("//mat-datepicker-toggle[@class='mat-datepicker-toggle']"));
this.calendar = element(by.xpath("//div[@class='mat-calendar-header']"));
this.calendar = element(by.xpath("//tbody[@class='mat-calendar-body']"));
this.routeArea;
this.countryOfOrigin = element(by.xpath("//mat-select[contains(@formcontrolname,'countryOfOriginId')]"));
this.countryList = element(by.xpath("//div[@class='select-option-cont']"))
this.userProfileRoute = element(by.xpath("//mat-select[contains(@formcontrolname,'assignToUserProfileId')]"));
this.userIcon=element(by.xpath("//a[@class='mat-menu-item']"));
this.Email = function (){
    this.userIcon.getText(this.userIcon).then(function (text){
   this.email=text.slice(5);
   console.log(this.email);
   return this.email
});
};`enter code here`
};
module.exports = new data();
```

Comment: It is likely that either your code is broken or you didn't copy all of it to your post. 
If you indent it properly, like I have just done in your question, you can see you never close the outer function block.

Comment: Your function `Email` does not have a `return` statement, so obviously it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should have been

```
this.Email = function (){
  return this.userIcon.getText(this.userIcon).then(function (text){
    this.email=text.slice(5);
    console.log(this.email);
    return this.email
});
```

Here is why - if you don't return a value from a function you can't reuse it

```
let my_func = function (a, b) {
  let some_var = a + b
}

let result = my_func(1,2);

console.log(result) // undefined
```

because you're missing return statement, so if you do

```
let my_func = function (a, b) {
  let some_var = a + b
  return some_var
}

let result = my_func(1,2);

console.log(result) // 3
```

The same happens if you do nested functions

```
let my_func_one = function (a, b) {
  let some_var = a + b
  return 
}

let my_func_two = (a,b) {
  my_func_one(a,b)
}

let result = my_func_two(1,2);

console.log(result) // undefined
```

that happens because your outer function doesn't return anything, but simply runs inner function. But if you have

```
let my_func_one = function (a, b) {
  let some_var = a + b
  return some_var
}

let my_func_two = (a,b) {
  return my_func_one(a,b) // return
}

let result = my_func_two(1,2);

console.log(result) // 3
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Sorry for bad code, beginner here :)